# Is there any way to run Handlebar Register helper after Handlebars.Compile

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I am creating inline editable form using HandleBars template, Everything is working fine but issue is i have some programs in database table and from there all active programs would be brought. Once user clicks to edit the course editable template is brought via `GET` request and compiled but i have to populate the select dropdown of the all active programs it would do `ajax` call and bring all the active programs so at this point i do not know how to run the Handlebars RegisterHelper to populate the data and  `set the selected value to edit the program` because the template has been compiled and executed already before ajax call The code i have written is as :
This will run and bring the template, after bringing the template it will compile and execute it.

```
  $(document).on("click", "#span", function () {
            $.get('/User/code/editbasicinfo.html', function (data) {

                $("#editabledata").append(data);
                var source = $("#some-template").html();
                var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
                var data = JSON.parse($('#JsonData').val());
                $("#editabledata").html(template(data));


            })

        });
```

when everything is compiled and appended it will call the template's `document.ready method` which is as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "ViewUserCourse.aspx/getdropdown",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            $("#Program").append(data.d);
            Handlebars.registerHelper("selected", function (foo, bar) {                  
                return foo == bar ? "selected" : "";
            });
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });

    $('#datashown').hide();     
});
```

this call will bring this json

```
 <option {{selected prog '0' }} value='0'>- Select -</option><option {{selected prog 'ABC' }} value='ABC'>ABC</option><option {{selected prog 'DEF' }} value='DEF'>DEF</option>"
```

at this point i would like to execut RegisterHelper named `selected` to set the selected value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in your template go to jQuery code

```
$(document).ready({});
```

After you get all of the append data you can use jQuery `prop` function to set the selected value

```
$('#<select> option[value="+ data.gender +"]').prop("selected", true);
```

If you want to use the handlebar for this then you will have to use  [partial Methods by HandleBar](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers).